# AngularJS ngAnimate ngView smooth fade out/in animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i like to have a nice transition while i change the content of my ngView. The user can always change the active view faster than the animation. Is there a way to always get an smooth fade out/in animation. The only way that is visible to seems to ignore fadeout/leave.

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/NedfHxWkdLg56FAlivUX?p=preview)

Comment: Try this : http://www.nganimate.org/

Comment: See this also with demo : https://github.com/Augus/ngAnimate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/NO0Xqh?p=preview.

With JavaScript controlled animation, it will make sure when user clicks faster than the animation, the value animation stop in the middle and reverse back to initial states.